# Move a Field from inner document to outer document

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I've got an assignment (I'm just now starting to learn MongoDb and NoSql) and I'm supposed to move the artist field from within the details document to the outer object. I have 19 objects within the songs collection they all follow the format below

```
{songId: 1, 
title: 'My Anaconda Dont',
details: 
       { 
        artist: 'Doesnt Matter', 
        album: 'Who Cares', 
        releaseYear: 1888
       }
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out what command to use to move the artist to be outside of the details document

Comment: Hi @eeelya welcome to stack overflow. What have you tried so far? Can you show us some of your code, and perhaps more of the structure of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tested on mongo v4.0.11

You can use the following query to update the existing collection data:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:{
            "artist":"$details.artist"
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "details.artist":0
        }
    },
    {
        $out: "collection"
    }
])
```

Sample output:

```
{
    "songId" : 1,
    "title" : "My Anaconda Dont",
    "details" : {
        "album" : "Who Cares",
        "releaseYear" : 1888
    },
    "artist" : "Doesnt Matter"
}
```

We performed aggregation on 'collection' and replaced the data of the same collection with the output of aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) in order to add artist at outer object and then [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the results like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      artist: "$details.artist"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      songId: 1,
      title: 1,
      artist: 1,
      details: {
        album: 1,
        releaseYear: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can find this running code here : https://mongoplayground.net/p/QEXXrP4fvaT